# How OSI and TCP/IP are related and different from each other

Tags: osi

As per my understanding OSI model is a specification of network layers
and TCP/IP is a protocol suit which gives a set of available protocols to be used in each layer which is defined in OSI.

But I am confused as some source say that both were created separately.

Comment: ![enter image description here](https://media.wiley.com/Lux/99/296299.image0.jpg) Read overview of OSI and TCP/IP from text books. See [Wikipedia link Comparison of OSI with TCP/IP model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Comparison_with_TCP.2FIP_model) And [Network Basics: TCP/IP and OSI Network Model Comparisons](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/network-basics-tcpip-and-osi-network-model-compari.html)

Comment: 'Some source'? *All* sources would say that, as it is the truth. What's confusing about that?

Answer (score 0):

> TCP/IP is a protocol suit which gives a set of available protocols to be used in each layer which is defined in OSI.

No it isn't. TCP/IP is a protocol suite which gives a set of available protocols to be used in each layer of the *TCP/IP* model. TCP/IP doesn't have anything to do with OSI whatsoever. The only thing that has to do with the OSI model is the OSI protocol suite.